# I got that: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: mar.tmx

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, tiled

```
Hi I'm trying to add tiled map but all time I'm getting the same error: 

"Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: mar.tmx
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:83)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:70)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:59)"
```

I saw a similar post and there someone said that my map has the wrong format but I tried every format and still the same. After debugging I got map = null. Anyone have any idea why it doesn't work?
LLL-----------------------
LLL------------------------
LLL-------------------------
LLL--------------------------
LLLL---------------------------
LLL-------------------------
LLL-----------------------

```
 package Screens;

    
    import Scenes.Hud;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;
    import com.mygdx.game.Marioxx;
    
    public class PlayScreen implements Screen
    {
        private com.mygdx.game.Marioxx game;
    
    
        private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
        private Viewport gamePort;
        //Tiled map variables
        private TmxMapLoader maploader;
        public TiledMap map;
        private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    
    
    
        private Hud hud;
    
        public PlayScreen(com.mygdx.game.Marioxx game)
        {
            this.game = game;
            gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
            gamePort = new FitViewport(Marioxx.V_WIDTH, Marioxx.V_HEIGHT, gamecam);
            hud = new Hud(game.batch);
    
            maploader = new TmxMapLoader();
            map = maploader.load("mar.tmx");
            renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
            gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getScreenWidth()/2, gamePort.getScreenHeight()/2, 0);
        }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        @Override
        public void show()
        {
    
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void render(float delta)
        {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
            hud.stage.draw();
    
            renderer.render();
    
        }
        public void handleInput(float dt )
        {
    
            if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
            {
                gamecam.position.x += 100* dt;
    
            }
    
        }
    
        public void update(float dt)
        {
    
    
             handleInput(dt);
    
             gamecam.update();
    
             renderer.setView(gamecam);
    
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void resize(int width, int height)
        {
    
            gamePort.update(width, height);
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void pause() {
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void resume() {
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void hide() {
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void dispose() {
    
            map.dispose();
            renderer.dispose();
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: By the fact the stack trace says "XmlReader.parse" I expect your map needs to be in XML, is that not the case?

Comment: No, I've already tried it and it hasn't worked.